# angular seed npm start

Tags: angularjs, angular-seed

I am trying to setup the angular-seed.
I have gone through the steps described in [angular-seed docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) which are:
1: clone the repo;
2: go in the root folder on my pc and install node with `npm install`;
3: start the project with `npm start`

After step 3 the result is displayed on the image below.
  http://postimg.org/image/wnkvgf473/ <<<===image of the output

Comment: i recommend for new guys to angular to let IDE make the terminal work.
1. install XAMPP to serve pages.
2. Download NETBEANS or other good IDE and press new project->angular-seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you get too attached to angular-seed, you might want to check out this comparison of the alternatives and make an informed decision

http://dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/

Answer (score 0):

The `events.js:72`  error typically means you already have an instance of node running.

Hit `CTRL+C` in your terminal already running node and try again.

Also when you run `npm start`  it'll automatically run `npm install` and `bower install` for you.